# In Kanboard, why do I get undefined index for this code whenever I click the button?

Tags: php, error-handling

In Kanboard, why do I get undefined index for this code whenever I click the button?

```
[php7:notice] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/.../public_html/app/Helper/LayoutHelper.php on line 90
[php7:notice] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: project in /var/www/.../public_html/app/Helper/LayoutHelper.php on line 91
```

```php
<?= $this->url->link(t('Delete'), 'ContactsItemsController', 'remove', array('item_id' => $item['id'], 'plugin' => 'AddressBook'), true, 'btn btn-red') ?>
```

I read that `isset` is a solution but if using `isset` is the solution, where do I place it?  I can't figure it out.

I tried:

```
<?= $this->url->link(t('Delete'), 'ContactsItemsController', 'remove', array('item_id' => isset($item['id']), 'plugin' => 'AddressBook'), true, 'btn btn-red') ?>
```

Comment: You need to give us some more context instead of just a single line with, for us, completely unknown variables/methods/functions. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Replace the line with this `... ( isset($item['id']) ? $item['id'] : '' ...` . You are checking whether the array `$item` contains an element with `id` as key or not. If yes, then use the element, else `''` use nothing. You can change the else part `: '' ` if you want.

Comment: Btw, `isset()` doesn't return the value, it only checks that the variable is defined and not null and returns a boolean (true if it is defined and not null, and false otherwise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `isset` you basically wrap around section where you use that array (or even simple variable), like:

```
<?php
if(isset($array['key'])){
    //... section where we can safely use the value of $array['key'] ...
    echo $this->url->link(...);
}
```

But you use the `<?=` which is shorthand for `<?php echo` and `echo` command must have an argument, even if its empty string or null, so you have to pass some value there, which limits your options how to wrap the section with `isset`.

You could use [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), like:

```
<?= isset($array['key']) ? /*... safe use of $array['key'] ...*/ $this->url->link(...) : '' ?>
```

Or [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) executed right away, like:

```
<?= (function(){ if(isset($array['key'])){ /*... safe use of $array['key'] ...*/ return $this->url->link(...); } })() ?>
```

Note that when you do not explicitly call `return` command, php functions implicitly return `null`. Also you should use this method for complex cases which you cannot solve by ternary operator, because of the readability, there could be multiple branches which are harder to get when you or someone else return to the code after while.

In case you care only about single value and not entire function call or even block, there is shorthand in form of [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce), like:

```
array('item_id' => $item['id'] ?? 0)
```

Which kinda does the `isset` check internally.

It looks way better then ternary operator, don't you think ?

```
array('item_id' => isset($item['id']) ? $item['id'] : 0)
```

To the warnings you posted: `Trying to access array offset on value of type null`, this means that the variable `$item` is set to null, therefore it is not an array. Code like this produce the same warning:

```
$item = null;
$item['id'];
```

Or the variable `$item` could be undefined, in which case there would be another warning `undefined variable $item`.

Most likely you are just setting the `$item` variable from database, but you are missing the check after that if you actually get the record.

Second warning is irrelevant to the code you posted `Undefined index: project`, this would happen in case like this:

```
$var = [];
$var['project'];
```

So you have variable which is an array, but there is no index/key named as *project* present in that array.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation was great and an answer for isset for other issues I was having so thanks for explaining that.

The fix for this particular problem was because I was using the `project` layout helper instead of the `config` one in the controller.

```php
/**
     * Contacts items config page
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function config()
    {
        $this->response->html($this->helper->layout->config('addressBook:config/index', array(
            'title' => t('Address Book Settings'),
            'items' => $this->contactsItemsModel->getAllItems(),
        )));
    }
```